# Sync up between two Nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I have 2 nexus repositories respectively for different development groups. Each repository will have its own hosted "Releases".

Now my question is:
 - Is it able to sync up these 2 Releases repo regularly? And how? I hope we don't need to ask development group to do any change.

Thank you very much

Comment: depends on your implementation. You could share that and ask what would work in it and what would not in terms on syncing the repo.

Comment: This is correct. I've answered given the limited amount of information available. If you expand on your use case, we can provide more information for you. If replication is your intent, Smart Proxy might serve you well in Nexus Repository Manager Pro 2.

Comment: https://github.com/030/n3dr

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we'd suggest you do this by creating a Proxy of the Hosted Repository on each Repository Manager instance. Proxies are used to bring a Hosted repository closer to you. With Repository Manager Pro you can use Smart Proxy to proactively sync them, or with OSS just rely on a regular Proxy to do so. You can read more about Proxy Repositories here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#proxy-repository

Comment: seems more like a comment unless supplemented with some explanation.

Comment: Added a bit more and a link to the background of Proxies :)

Comment: The problem is that after creating a proxy repository, I didn't see any items coming from the source repositories.  Is the “Repository Manager Pro” a must?

Comment: To use Smart Proxy, yes. A normal proxy is dumb by design, it will only hold what you request from it.

Comment: I have tested that with the path of a known file, but I only get response 404. Is there anything I have to configure different then standard proxy?  I have created on nexusV3 instance a proxy repo with the URL of the hosted repo from our nexusV2 instance, but no luck.